# How to manipulate blocks of rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

I have a big db (240 million rows) divided into blocks, with start of block mark (sob) as one of the columns, 1.3 million blocks.

I've created a block_start series:

```
block_start = pd.series(df[df.sob == True].index)
```

and calculate the blocks lengths series:

```
block_len = block_start.shift(-1) - block_start.
```

Now I need to find whether each block contains at least one signal (true) in a Boolean column:

```
signals = []

for i in range(len(block_start)):
 signals.append(df.signal[block_start[i]:block_start[i]+block_len[i]].any())
```

The above loop takes 20 minutes.
Any ideas how to shortened it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `groupby` + `cumsum` + `any`

You can `groupby` the cumulative sum of your `sob` series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'signal': [True, False, True, False, False,
                              False, True, False, False, False],
                   'sob': [True, False, False, False, True,
                           False, False, True, False, False]})

df['any_flag'] = df.groupby(df['sob'].cumsum())['signal'].transform('any')

print(df)

   signal    sob  any_flag
0    True   True      True
1   False  False      True
2    True  False      True
3   False  False      True
4   False   True      True
5   False  False      True
6    True  False      True
7   False   True     False
8   False  False     False
9   False  False     False
```

Comment: Thanks, its great, 20 seconds instead of 20 minutes!

Answer (score 2):

For blazing<sup>1</sup> performance, you may want to let NumPy take over.
(Data borrowed from @jpp's answer)

```
v = np.cumsum(df['sob'])
df['any_flag'] = v.isin(v[df.signal].unique())

print(df)
   signal    sob  any_flag
0    True   True      True
1   False  False      True
2    True  False      True
3   False  False      True
4   False   True      True
5   False  False      True
6    True  False      True
7   False   True     False
8   False  False     False
9   False  False     False
```

<sub>1. Your mileage may vary.</sub>

---

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df['any_flag'] = (
    df.groupby(df['sob'].cumsum())['signal'].transform('any'))
%%timeit 
v = np.cumsum(df['sob'])
df['any_flag'] = v.isin(v[df.signal].unique())

10.9 ms ± 610 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
4.5 ms ± 19.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```